# Negative filterVertices option for traversal

Tags: arangodb

The `GRAPH_TRAVERSAL` has an option called `filterVertices`, which the documentation states will be used to only allow those vertices matching the examples to go through. Is there any negative version of this, e.g. to allow everything *except* those matching the filter?

In many cases this would be useful, e.g. traverse everything *except* those marked *disabled* (or *old-version*) or something like that. Of course this can be done with a JS function, but why not built-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, its currently not possible, and if you want to use `GRAPH_TRAVERSAL` you have to write your own visitor function.

However, the recommended way is to use the [new pattern matching](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/GraphTraversals.html) where you can use `FILTER` statements like this:

```
db._query("FOR vertex IN 1..3 OUTBOUND 'circles/A' GRAPH
          'traversalGraph' FILTER vertex._key != 'G' return v._key")
         .toArray();
```

so you can use arbitrary filter expressions on vertices, edges and paths and their sub-parts.

In general our development focus will be on the pattern matching traversals and doing as much as is possible in AQL. If you like to implement such a feature for the general graph module, Contributions are always welcome.

Comment: Then how about:  FILTER "key_of_blocked_subtree_root" not in vertices[*]._key? That should enable me to give a sub tree root and prohibit traversal to go down below that node?    And if I have multiple forbidden sub trees FILTER LENGTH (INTERSECTION (@@forbidden_subtree_roots, vertices[*]))>1 could work? If so the new syntax is indeed powerful.

Comment: If I get that correctly, you want to test for properties of the n'th traversal depth? You can have `FOR vertex, edge, path IN..... FILTER path.edges[2]..... == .... AND FILTER .... RETURN ...`

Comment: I want to stop traversal into a subtree giving the root vertex of the subtree as a filter parameter. I do not know how deep to traverse before meeting that root, so I can't filter on vertex[n] because I don't know n. I also want to give multiple root vertices of subtrees I do not want to traverse into.

Comment: simple filters on `vertex` will be executed before each traversal step. The [traversal graph documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/GraphTraversals.html) explains in depth with nice pictures whats possible. Try to create a query, use `explain` to inspect it, and lets discuss that then. Probably the google group is a better medium for such a discussion than stackoverflow.